# CakePHP 2.x MSSQL 2008 Connect

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp

I have CakePHP 2.x and PHP 5.4.3 on my Windows machine (Windows 8, using WAMP). I have to connect on other mssql server because I need some data from there. I already tried so many ways to connect but 
error message is always the same:

```
Error: A Database connection using "Sqlserver" was missing or unable to connect. 
The database server returned this error: Selected driver is not enabled

Error: Sqlserver driver is NOT enabled
```

My database.php configuration:

```
public $urniki = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'somehost.com',
    'login' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'db',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Any idea how to connect this?

Comment: Found solution at:http://robsphp.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the SQLServer driver for PHP installed and this line is in your php.ini

```
Extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```

See this for more details: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php